# C# exclusive enum

Tags: c#

I am trying to use enum to represent different types for an order. But there is no compiler support to ensure the values are mutually exclusive. For example, I could have a totally leagle enum as

```
public enum MySearchType{
    SearchByName = 1,
    SearchById = 2,
    SearchByOrderNumber = 2 //I really meant to have 3, but overlooked. 
                            //so I would like compiler to give me an error here.
}
```

Is there anyway in c# to achieve what I want to do?

Comment: Why to supply the numbers? It would automatically give unique auto increment ids to them.

Comment: I think what @AshishCharan said is the closest you'll get. If you leave the numbers out of the enum, it will auto-increment them for you. Other than that, it's perfectly valid to have different enum values using the same integer.

Comment: @AshishCharan, There is a reason to manually supply a number for each value. I don't remember exactly, but it has something to do with dll versioning.

Comment: There's no way to enforce this declaratively, but if you really want to be sure, you can always use Reflection to verify uniqueness at run time. Not sure why you would want to, though...

Comment: I am curious what the requirement is for specifying the values. Can you explain?

Comment: It's especially important for `[Flags]` enums, where the values really need to be `1 << position`

Comment: George's answer is the usual way to avoid this problem.

Answer (score 2):

The standard thing to do when you need an order in a c# enum is to order only the first value and let the rest auto-increment

```
public enum MySearchType{
    SearchByName = 1,
    SearchById,          //implicitly 2
    SearchByOrderNumber, //implicitly 3
}
```

I believe (and I could be wrong here) that enum instances in c# are implemented simply as an integer alias so there really is no way to ensure no duplicates (nor would you want to, it makes perfect sense sometimes to allow aliases for the same enum value).

Perhaps you want a `Dictionary<int, string>` or `IEnumerable<Tuple<string, int>>` with `.Distinct()` called on it instead?

Comment: The approved types for an enum are `byte`, `sbyte`, `short`, `ushort`, `int`, `uint`, `long`, or `ulong`. ([source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx))

Comment: Good point, I guess I was trying to say that enums are just labels for a value of a simple primitive type.

Comment: Agreed and +1'd, was simply additional info

Comment: Note that if you intend to use a `[Flags]` enum with bitflags, there really is no solution. It has to be done manually.